# How to improve the cloud service performance in Windows azure?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, azure

Presently my application is running in staging environment. I need to release my application to market, but before that I want to come out of this performance issues and my application details are,

Cloud Services       =============> West US

Storage Account          ============> West US

Database Server          ===========> North Central US

VM(Virtual Machine) Size  =====> Small

here my cloud service and storage in one location and Database Server in another location.is that any effects on application performance?

and one more thing am using the one web role with one instance in my application.

Can you suggest me what changes will I do for improving my application performance?

Comment: First thing you will do is actually set performance goals and measure performance. Than see if application meets your goals. Than identify what needs to be improved and ask concrete questions if needed.

Answer (score 3):

You definitely should put your database and services in the same region. Database performance is most likely your performance achilles heel and you should be putting the database as 'close' as possible to your services. Having your database and services in the same region means that they are in the same datacentre and therefore on a high-speed backbone. Separate regions (datacentres) means that your data has to traverse lower speed trans-national infrastructure — both throughput and latency will suffer badly. Also, since data egress charges are by region, you will be paying for all the traffic from your database to the application — with them in the same region this will not cost a cent.

Other performance improvements can be made — look at the CPU load on your cloud service, for example, to determine if a single instance is enough. But start with the data. Get data as close to the service as possible, starting with region affinity, but also looking at caching (where the data is in memory on the same machine).

Comment: Hi Simon,I want to change my database region from North Central US to West US. Is it available in Windows azure?

Comment: I don't think it is possible to move regions. You would have to backup your North Central US one and restore it to a new database in West US. There are a [few options for doing backup/restore](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj650016.aspx)

Comment: Hi to All,Now i created a new server in West US location and now my application performance good.Thanks to all.

Answer (score 1):

From the description above, a few things you would need to do first:

1. Make sure your database server and cloud service are in the same region (West US). Having your cloud service and database servers in different regions would create some latency issues.
2. In the production environment, you would need to ensure that you're running at least 2 instances of your web role. A single instance web role is not covered by Windows Azure SLA and if this single instance goes down for any reason, your application is unavailable for that duration.

After that, please follow @Alexei Levenkov's recommendation on setting up performance goals.

Comment: Not only can having the db server in a different region cause latency issues, but you might also get [charged](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/pricing/details/#header-11) for data transfers between regions.

Comment: Good point Tom! I completely forgot about data egress charges.

Comment: Thanks for your Information,but one thing i ask you about database creation in windows azure.when i try to create a cloud service and strorage account in North Central US am not getting that(North Central US) region.so what i ask you how can i arrange all(Cloud Service,Storage Account and Database)to one region.can u suggest  me please.

Comment: I think you can't create any new resources in North Central US data center (and also in South Central US as well) as I believe it has reached its quota. You may want to choose a different data center like East US or West US.

Comment: Gaurav,your saying now am create a new server in different region(like East US).